# Image files added in Resources/drawable in Android cannot be found

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to add a custom marker on a custom map. The marker png image file was added to Resources/drawable in Android folder. But when I called the below line, the image file name was flagged with red underline. Hovering over it, I saw the message 'Resource.Drawable' does not contain a definition for 'orange_pin_thick_outline_nofill'. The image file's  Build Action is set to AndroidResource. I also tried EmbeddedResouce. But the result is the same.
It looks like that none of the image files are recognizable. Those that did show up after I typed Resource.Drawable are probably some built-in images. Any idea how can I get my marker image using FromResource()?

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.orange_pin_thick_outline_nofill)
```

Comment: I think it is Visual studio problem, not your code error, you don't care this error message, clean your project and try to build project.

Answer (score 1):

Try the full name by adding the file Extension.

try this :

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("your_image.png");
```

or :

```
BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromView(new BindingPinView("", "your_image.png"));
```

Comment: BitmapDescriptorFactory does not have methods FromBundle() or FromView(). All I can see after typing BitmapDescriptorFactory.From are FromArray(), FromAsset(), FromBitmap(), FromFile(), FromPath(), FromResource().